# ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry() $data argument

Tags: channel-entries, channel-entries-api

Based on the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#save-entry), here is the signature for the method that inserts a new entry or update an existing one.

```
ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, $channel_id, $entry_id, $autosave);
```

My question is that, what should be the contents for $data?

Say for example I have Channel A which has only one custom field, "foo"

Do I do this?

```
$data = array (
    'title' => 'bar',
    'url_title' => 'bar'
    'foo' => 'bar'
);
```

or this?

```
$data = array (
    'title' => 'bar',
    'url_title' => 'bar'
    'field_id_<field id of foo>' => 'bar'
);
```

Or is the contents of `$data` should be something else entirely? Do I need to input required field?

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty late answer, and you likely already figured it out, but the $data array should use the database 'field_id_#' as the array key.  So if the field id of your custom field 'foo' is 5, for example, then your data array would be:

```
$data = array (
    'title' => 'bar',
    'url_title' => 'bar',
    'field_id_5' => 'bar',
);
```